# ColdFusion Session Issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I’m creating a session base shopping cart with CFWheels framework 1.1.8. I’m having a strange problem where the ColdFusion 9 session does not persist. I spent countless hours check and double checking my code. I’m hoping a fresh of eye can spot what I’ve missed. Below is a simplify version of my code. Any suggestion would be GREATLY appreciated.

**config/app.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
    this.name = hash(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())
                  , "SHA-256");   
    this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0);
    this.loginStorage = "session";
    this.sessionManagement = true;
    this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
    this.setClientCookies = false; 
    this.setDomainCookes = false;
</cfscript>
```

**Events/onRequestStart.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
   if (! StructKeyExists(session, "cart")){
       session.cart = arrayNew(1);
   }
</cfscript>
```

**Controllers/Cart.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller">

   <cffunction name="index">    
   </cffunction>

   <cffunction name="create">
       <cfset  arrayAppend(session.cart, structNew())>
       <cfset index = arrayLen(session.cart)>
       <cfset session.cart[index].title = "Product Name">
       <cfset session.cart[index].quantity = "1">
       <!--- 
           this return the expect cart array with product. 
           The item disappears once it gets redirected to the index page 
       --->
       <cfdump var="#session.cart#" abort>

       <cfset redirectTo(action="index")>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

**Views/cart/index.cfm**

```
<!--- this return an empty array (same in all other web page)--->
<cfdump var="#session.cart#">
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by commenting out the (`this.setClientCookies = false;`) in the config/app.cfm.

Answer (score 0):

changing setClientCookies=true is simply using the cookies to track the session. In order to use session management without cookies you need to set a sessionTimout with application.cfm or onSessionStart using Application.cfc. If you want to get it running correctly or for anyone who stumbles accross this post I am including some links. Ben does a great job explaining Application.cfc with example.

[Bens Tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm)